# Is there a client app like MongoDB Compass for Firebase Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, nosql, database-management

I've started using Firebase Firestore on a project. The Firestore management tool seems very basic and doesn't have things like a query editor, ability to duplicate records etc...

Is there a client application like MongoDB Compass or Sequel Pro for Firebase Firestore?

Comment: Great question. Compass is very cool. Did you find anything?

Comment: @WesleyBarnes Unfortunately I  couldn't find a good client app for it and I have come to the conclusion that firestore and nosql databases in general not well suited for a main application database. My recommendation would be that if you can use a relational database like mysql and only use nosql for special cases.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I think my next project will be back to sql

Comment: @JackVial I must say that your conclusion of noSQL databases is not so correct. Firestore is not so scalable since its purpose is to power small scale mobile apps. I've worked even on a FinTech product with noSQL as there primary DB for most of the cases except payments where using a relational database makes more sense.